# DataSnapshot child returning null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason, the snapshot child "body" is returning NULL, but the title isn't... Really not sure why as title is returning it's value just fine. Using Java.

[image]

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mPostsRef = mRef.child("Posts");
String userKey = "-LAKM7c_1Pr7g872svLA"; // Just for testing purposes

mPostsRef.child(userKey).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class);
            String body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue(String.class);

            Log.d("testing", "Title: " + title + " | Body: " + body);
        }

    });
```

My Log.d:

> Title: test 1 | Body: null
>
> Title: test 2 | Body: null

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you initialize `mPostsRef` and `userKey`?

Comment: Yes sir. Done that

Comment: use `String body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue().toString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
String body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue(String.class);
```

into this:

```
String body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue().toString();
```

Comment: Hm.. Getting this when I add another post:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference

It's still the body that is causing the problem

Comment: why are u using childeventlistener?

Comment: Because for some reason it's adding posts to the list view more than once. It really acts funky and I don't know why. I also need to be able to do something specific if a post has been removed

Comment: if u use valueeventlistener it will also add posts to the listview more than once

Comment: Sorry, I meant it duplicates a post like 3 times. So, if I edit the data on the post, it'll re-add to the listview because it's using onDataChanged (which detects anything). That make sense?

Comment: if you use ValueEventListener then it will trigger on the changes in the database at the location provided https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener.html#onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot)

Comment: That's right. Not sure why it's giving me an error though. When I restart my app, it displays the data just fine. But, when I go to add another post, it's throwing me that error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169268/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-jonathon).

Comment: @PeterHaddad When reading a string value from the database, I don't see how `getValue(String.class)` gives a different result than `getValue().toString()`. Can you explain why the code you gave makes a difference. I usually recommend against using `toString()`, since it's a more implicit type conversion.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no idea honestly, I had this problem before and when I changed it to `toString()` it worked even though both should give the same value

Comment: Can you see if you can reproduce that in a minimal context, and open a question for it. As far as I know (and have experienced) there shouldn't be a difference (and the `toString()` *might* throw an NPE, which the other variant doesn't, or throws only later).

Answer (score 2):

try this !

```
DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference mPostsRef = mRef.child("Posts");
String userKey = "-LAKM7c_1Pr7g872svLA"; // Just for testing purposes

mPostsRef.child(userKey).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

       for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
          {
             Object title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
             Object body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue();

               Log.d("testing", "Title: " + title + " | Body: " + body);
          }


        }

    });
```

Comment: Opps. I miss read your answer. The for loop wont work. However, this works:
Object title = dataSnapshot.child("title").getValue();
             Object body = dataSnapshot.child("body").getValue();